# Night Light not working on one out of three monitor

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, night-light

I am currently on ubuntu 22.04.1.

My setup: I have 2 monitors connected to my nvidia gtx 1060 graphics card, one with hdmi and one with dvi, and I have a third display connected to my iGPU with DVI.

The problem is that Gnome Night Light works only on the DVI monitors. I can use Redshift to make it work on all three, but after a while seems like redshift stops working on the same displays that Gnome Night Light works, and it works only on the HDMI display (where Gnome Night Light does not work).

So far I tried using these 2 commands

```
systemctl --user restart [org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.target](https://org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.target)
```

```
killall -9 gsd-color
```

But they seem to work only for the 2 displays where Gnome Night Light does already work, it doesnt do anything for the HDMI display.

Someone has any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can use Redshift to make it work on all three, but after a while
> seems like redshift stops working on the same displays that Gnome
> Night Light works, and it works only on the HDMI display (where Gnome
> Night Light does not work).

I figured out a solution for this. If I stop what I believe the Gnome Night Light uses to function, then it won't reset my Redshift configuration.

In short:

1. I run `$ systemctl stop colord.services`
2. I run `$ redshift -O 5000` (which is the command to set the temperature with Redshift).

After doing this, Redshift works as intended.

I was not able to make native Gnome Night Light work, but Redshift is a good replacement.